# Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) User cannot access this application only when uploading photos to facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Friends,

I am working with FB SDK using PhP and everything is working fine except one case. I am able to post messages, links etc to FB from my app using the below code.

```
$fb->api('me/feed','POST', array('access_token' => ACCESS_TOKEN, 'message' => 'hello world!'));
```

When trying to post an image using the below code, it throws **Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) User cannot access this application**

```
$fb->api('/'.$GROUP_ID.'/photos?access_token='. $facebook->getAccessToken(), 'POST',
                array(
                        'source' => '@' . $img,
                        'message' => 'This photo came from my app.'
                )
```

Any ideas on why this could happen? I have searched almost all possible solutions in StackOverflow and search engines, but nothing works.

FYI, I am making the Login URL using below code -

```
$loginUrl = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'   => 'publish_stream user_groups publish_actions',
        'redirect_uri' => $site_url,
    ));
```

Also, the App has all required extended permissions setup in FB.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your scope is wrong – this parameter expects a _comma-separated_ list of permission names, not with spaces in between.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. I just tried and even passing the scope as 'scope'   => 'publish_stream,user_groups,publish_actions' it does not work. The point to note is it posts text messages and links OK, but does not post images. :(

Comment: When you say 'it does not post images' could you be more specific?

Comment: @Igy With that I mean, I want to post an image to a FB group as an image not as a link. I will upload an image from my PC and want it to be posted on FB group. Hope its clear now :)

Comment: Have you initialized the Facebook class with file uploads set to true?

Comment: Yes...I have initialized it using setFileUploadSupport() just before trying to upload a file

Answer (score 0):

Insted of "$fb->api('/'.$GROUP_ID.'/photos?" use "$fb->api('/'.$ALBUM_ID.'/photos?"
i.e. use any of the existing album id or do not mention any album id. In second case, it will create a new album for your application